# Is it possible to disable MDC logging fields in logback for a specific appender/logger?

Tags: java, logging, logback, mdc

I need to add an additional logging layer to a project (SpringBoot+LogBack). Currently some fields are added to the MDC to be included in the logs, which is fine.

In the new logging layer, I use a new appender and logger and I need to exclude the MDC fields from these log entries, is that possible?

Comment: If you are using a new appender you can specify a new `<pattern>` for it and therefore you can define which MDC fields are included into the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, posting it as an answer to save time for others. It is possible using [logback logstash encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#mdc-fields). You simply can add `<includeMdc>false</includeMdc>` to the appender.